# Gensim Doc2Vec Exception AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'words'

Tags: python, neural-network, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am learning `Doc2Vec` model from `gensim` library and using it as follows:

```
class MyTaggedDocument(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            with open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname),encoding='utf-8') as fin:
                print(fname)
                for item_no, sentence in enumerate(fin):
                    yield LabeledSentence([w for w in sentence.lower().split() if w in stopwords.words('english')], [fname.split('.')[0].strip() + '_%s' % item_no])
sentences = MyTaggedDocument(dirname)
model = Doc2Vec(sentences,min_count=2, window=10, size=300, sample=1e-4, negative=5, workers=7)
```

The input `dirname` is a directory path which has , for the sake of simplicity, only 2 files located with each file containing more than 100 lines. I am getting following Exception.

[image: Output]

Also, with `print` statement I could see that the iterator iterated over directory 6 times. Why is this so?

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: One thing, don't you want if w not in stopwords? Right now your sentences only contain stopwords

Comment: Yeah that's a mistake, i corrected it but still the same problem persist.

Comment: https://medium.com/@gofortargets/doc2vec-word2vec-in-gensim-c9321c780079

Comment: https://medium.com/@gofortargets/doc2vec-word2vec-in-gensim-c9321c780079

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one of the text-example objects, which should be shaped like a `TaggedDocument` (with `words` and `tags` properties, formerly called `LabeledSentence`), is somehow a plain string instead. Are you 100% certain that the error in your screenshot was generated by exactly the iterable code you've included? (The code here looks like it could only emit acceptable `LabeledSentece` objects.)

Your supplied corpus Iterable is read once to do an initial scan which discovered all words/tags, then again multiple times for training. How many times is controlled by the `iter` parameter, with a default value (in recent versions of gensim) of 5. So the initial scan plus 5 training passes equal 6 total iterations. (10 or more iterations is common with Doc2Vec.)